# Installing Python silently

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I have my code written in python 3.6.5. I am trying make this an installable package (something like install shield) and wanted to bundle python software also along with this installshield. OS is Windows

1. Will python work by unzipping the installation directory and then setting path variable?
2. When I use /quiet for silent installation of python, I could not change the path of installation directory to my choice, say in my case C:\test(even after setting TargetDir=C:\test). Where am I going wrong?
3. If there any other approach to bundle installation of python along with installation package can someone let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Pyinstaller? If python is set to path you can run from CMD pip install pyinstaller. Then you can create a standalone exe that will include the python packages to run. Hold shift and open a CMD where your script is and then run a command similar to this

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --icon=data.ico --version-file=Version.txt -F LineQuery.py
```

The -F is the standalone package. Be aware though that you need to copy the DLLs from microsoft runtime visual c++ 2015 into the python DLL folder usually located at C:\Users\"user"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs. That is if you package it on windows 10. Otherwise you'll have issues with your program running on earlier versions of windows.

The standalone package will be slow at startup. You can package it into a folder that will be faster. Just remove the -F